# Append elements from external dict into dict inside assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Hello, everyone.**

Is there a way in python to insert all items from one dictionary to another inside variable assignment?

```
dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
dict2 = {"d": 4, #INSERT THERE ALL FROM "dict1"#, "e": -1}
```

Maybe there's smth like `{key: value for key, value in temp.items()}` or other "hack"?

I know that there's *update()* method and I've already applied it, but it looks a bit weird. **Order of entries matters** so to build dict in proper order I need to write next code :

```
dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
dict2 = {"d: 4"}
dict2.update(dict1)
dict2.update({"e": -1, "f": -2})
```

Hope there's a way to do it more "nice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict2 = {"d": 4, **dict1, "e": -1}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for!